# soapfault soapserver fault string

Tags: android, ksoap2, soapfault

hiii all ,  I am getting soap fault exception type of
'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException

my code is 
SoapObject soapRequest = new SoapObject(nameSpace,methodName);

```
    //soapRequest.addProperty("GetListResult", "TEST");

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope  = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapSerializationEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.dotNet=true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapRequest);

    HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(url);


    //AndroidHttpTransport httpTransport;


    try {

        System.out.println("calling service");
        transport.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelope);

        System.out.println("calling complete getting result");


        //SoapObject soapResult = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;


        System.out.println("soap result is "+envelope.getResponse());

    } catch (IOException e) {



        System.out.println("IOExceptio");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        System.out.println("XmlPullParserException");

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting a SoapFault the problem is on the server and not on Android. Verify the request Android creates by using debug setting and the requestdump and test it with a tool like SoapUi. And then debug the problem on the server.

Comment: as I am new to android i dont know how to do it can u please help me more?

Comment: Read the wiki for the ksaop2 android website. I documented it all there.